# Why am I getting a name Error When I run in sublime Repl?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I don't understand why I am getting these errors and why its not at least running through the second user input prompt. new to sublime. Also are the for loops necessary in the functions. Did I mess up the calls to the functions, or should the logical ordering of the user inputs and functions be different.

Here is the error, Ive also gotten an EOF error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 17, in <module>
    user_name = input("Enter a username ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'daY123ytt' is not defined
```

Here is my code

```
print ("Welcome please sign up and create a Username and Password")

print ("Password must be 8 characters, have an uppercase and lowercase and a number and special character ")

login = {}

user_name = input("Enter a username ")
pass_word = input("Enter a password ")


def user_signup():
    for x in name:
        if user_name >= len(8):
            print ("user name is too long ")
        elif user_name == pass_word:
            print ("user name is taken")
        else:
            login["Username"]= user_name
        #else append to login dict


import re

def pass_signup():
    for x in pass_word:
        regx = re.compile('!@#$%^&*()<>?/\|{}[];:')
        if (regx.search(string) == None):
            print ("Need Special charcter")
        elif len(pass_word) <= 6:
            print ("Password must be at least 8 characters")
        elif len(pass_word.upper()) < 1 and len(pass_word.lower()) < 1:
            print ("Must have Uppercase and Lowercase characters ")
        else:
            login["Password"]= pass_word
        #else append to login dict:

user_name = input("Enter username")
pass_word = input("Enter password")

def userpass_checker():
    if username == login["Username"] and password == login["Password"]:
        file.open()
    else:
        print ("Try again ")

user_checker()
pass_checker()
userpass_checker()
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you are using python2, try replace `input` with `raw_input` instead.